# How to create a test user in test/fixtures/user.yml that can be used for integration test in Devise 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

As you can see from the codes below, I already created a user in `users.yml`, included the devise's helper for integration test in `test_helper.rb` (that's why I was able to use the `sign_in` method - based on [Devise's README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#integration-tests)), and have a passing integration test in `site_layout_test.rb`.

My question is, when I tried to comment-out the `email`, `encrypted_password`, and `created_at` params of user john in `users.yml`, I still have a passing test but my newbie mind tells me that I should have a failing test now since user john is now not a valid user.

What's happening here? Why am I still having a passing test?

By the way, this is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671832/how-to-log-in-out-users-with-devise-in-rails4-testing) that helped me how to create a user in `users.yml`

> test/fixtures/users.yml

```
john:
  name: John Rockefeller
  email: john@rockefeller.com
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'password') %>
  created_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

> test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  include ApplicationHelper
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
end
```

> test/integration/site_layout_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @user = users(:john)
  end

  test "layout links" do
    # Not signed in
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", new_user_session_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", new_user_registration_path
    get new_user_registration_path
    assert_template 'devise/registrations/new'
    assert_select "title", full_title("Sign up")
    get new_user_session_path
    assert_template 'devise/sessions/new'
    assert_select "title", full_title("Sign in")
    # Signed in
    sign_in @user
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", new_user_session_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", new_user_registration_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", edit_user_registration_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", destroy_user_session_path
    get edit_user_registration_path
    assert_template 'devise/registrations/edit'
    assert_select "title", full_title(@user.name)
  end
end
```

EDIT: SOLVED! My new `site_layout_test.rb` below:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @user = users(:john)
  end

  test "non-signed in user layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", new_user_session_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", new_user_registration_path
  end

  test "signed in user layout links" do
    get new_user_session_path
    assert_template 'devise/sessions/new'
    post user_session_path, params: { user: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' } }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_path
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", new_user_session_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", new_user_registration_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", edit_user_registration_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", destroy_user_session_path
  end

  test "page title" do
    get new_user_registration_path
    assert_template 'devise/registrations/new'
    assert_select "title", full_title("Sign up")
    get new_user_session_path
    assert_template 'devise/sessions/new'
    assert_select "title", full_title("Sign in")
  end
end
```

Comment: I would spit the test into several examples with a limited number of assertions. Grouping everything into a single test block is a horrible practice which leads to ordering issues. Arrange Act Assert.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. What can you say about my question though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to keep in mind.

First, fixtures are inserted directly into the database. The corresponding model is *not* instantiated. As a consequence, it's possible to insert values which would make model-level validations fail.

Second, `sign_in` simply sets the user ID in the session (you can think of it as `session[:user_id] = @user.id`). It performs *no* authentication. It should be used when testing a feature *other* than authentication (e.g. posting as a user on a forum). It skips the whole request-response cycle related to authentication and lets you go straight to the controller and action you want to test.

In order to test authentication you should fire a `POST` request against `new_sessions_path` (please substituted the route names you use in your app):

```
post new_sessions_path, params: { email: '...', password: '...' }
```

Last but not least, I recommend you split your test into many smaller tests. Especially that you named it `layout links` but you test sign in which is confusing.

Comment: Okay now I get it. Thanks @Greg!

Comment: So basically creating a user in `users.yml` is like creating a new user in web interface. And I just need to `sign_in` that user through `post new_user_session_path ...`

Comment: Not exactly. When you register a new user there are a bunch of components that are involved: controllers, views, models, database, etc. When you add an entry to a fixture file it gets inserted into the table directly. So creating a user in `users.yml` can be compared to connecting to your database directly and running `INSERT INTO users VALUES (...)`. If you want to test something else than a sign in then use `sign_in` to skip authentication. If you want to test authentication itself you need to use `get`, `post`, etc. to interact with the controller directly.

Comment: Yes, that looks better.