# Rails test fixture user's email showing as null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, fixtures

I am trying to test that a login system works correctly. I have created a user fixture with a test user.

**test/fixtures/users.yml**

```
dave:
  name: Mr Dave
  email: dave@dave.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

I have created a unit test for the login system, which tests the user login and logout.

**test/integration/site_layout_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

def setup
    @user = users(:dave)
end

...

  test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, params: { session: { email:    @user.email,
                                          password: 'password' } }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end
end
```

When I try to run the test I get an error stating there is no email method for a NilClass.

```
Error:
SiteLayoutTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout:
NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
    test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:35:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'
```

Why is Rails not picking up the user I added to the fixtures folder?

Comment: Could you post your whole test file?

Comment: Anyway, my guess is that `setup` is outside the test suite class and is therefore not being run, is that possible?

Comment: Your guess is correct. It is both possible and also true.

Comment: Great, I made an answer just for fun to close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `setup` is outside the test class and therefore doesn't run. Move it inside the class declaration and it will work smoothly.

```
class SomeTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @user = users(:dave)
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it should put you in the right direction, let me know if you are still having problems [How to create a test user in test/fixtures/user.yml that can be used for integration test in Devise 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140424/how-to-create-a-test-user-in-test-fixtures-user-yml-that-can-be-used-for-integra)

Comment: I'm not certain which part I should be looking at. My routes.rb file contains `'/login',      to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',      to: 'sessions#create'` so as far as I can tell the routing is correct, which seems to have been the problem with the code in the question you're linking to. Or did you mean something else about the question?

Comment: I was pointing out to the fact that your test WAS NOT setup correctly, as Iceman well pointed above, your `setup` was outside the test class and therefore it would not run properly.

Comment: I see. I can understand why you might have preferred to hint rather than point it out, as in a way it's one of the 'doh!' moments, which I'm sure happens even to the best of us (a Google dev who's working on the newest version of Angular recently went through an entire presentation with `@Comonent` as a variable name instead of `@Component`, for example). However, if the solution to the problem had been explicitly stated I would have been able to accept and up-vote your answer, which in the event I was not able to.